# Access site from azure which required VPN

Tags: c#, azure

I have .NET Core APIS. these APIS accessing some end points of other website and it can be access using VPN connection only, so when I test it in my local machine It works because I have active VPN connection. Now When I am publishing this API as a service on azure, It's returning me error that **No host is know**. How can I allow azure to access that third party website with VPN connection

Comment: I think the problem is about network and VPN configurations, not Net Core neither c#

Comment: @Frank yes definitely. Is there any reference on how can I allow azure to access 3rd party site with VPN